# Mongo DB Remote Server Connection Issue in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, remote-server

I need to know about the Mongo DB Remote Server Connection using in Meteor.As i did something shown below :

```
database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://x.x.x.x:3001/dbname");
```

I got the below error :

```
I20150121-11:51:14.066(5.5)? Exception in callback of async function: Error: failed to connect to [x.x.x.x:3001]
I20150121-11:51:14.066(5.5)?     at null.<anonymous> (/home/abc/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.0.8.hj5n7c++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:536:74)
I20150121-11:51:14.066(5.5)?     at emit (events.js:106:17)
I20150121-11:51:14.066(5.5)?     at null.<anonymous> (/home/abc/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.0.8.hj5n7c++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:150:15)
I20150121-11:51:14.066(5.5)?     at emit (events.js:98:17)
I20150121-11:51:14.066(5.5)?     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/abc/.meteor/packages/mongo/.1.0.8.hj5n7c++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:516:10)
I20150121-11:51:14.067(5.5)?     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
I20150121-11:51:14.067(5.5)?     at net.js:440:14
I20150121-11:51:14.067(5.5)?     at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

How to solve the above error using Meteor.So please suggest me what to do for this.

Comment: Try connecting to it using `mongo` from the remote machine, perhaps meteor is binding ports/ip to that computers IP only?

Comment: Can you please give me exactly what i can do?.@Akshat

Comment: You need `mongo`, (from mongodb.org), you can connect using `mongo x.x.x.x -p 3001`, if it gives a connection error then there is no issue with the code, but rather with the mongodb server not being publicly exposed

Comment: You seem to try to connect to the local MongoDB instance that is started by Meteor itself. Not sure if there are any checks that prevent form connecting to the same DB twice (Meteor automatically connects to the port 3001 instance). The code itself works fine for me, so it must be either a transport-level or a Mongo error.